# Manage accented characters in string

Tags: batch-file, character-encoding

I am trying to make a simple batch script to compare two files and open them if it found a difference.
So I use FC to compare the files; if no difference is found, it'll send me this text:

```bash
Comparaison des fichiers FILE1 et FILE2
FC : aucune différence trouvée
```

As you can see, it's in French, and it contains accented characters. That's my problem.
So here's my code so far:

```bash
@echo off
set "FILE1=file1path"
set "FILE2=file2path"
set "edit=editorpath"
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('fc /A /C /N "%FILE1%" "%FILE2%"') do (
    set "DIFF=%%F"
)

set "NODIFF=FC : aucune différence trouvée"
if /I "%DIFF%"=="%NODIFF%" (
    echo "no difference found"
) else (
    start "" %edit% %FILE1%
    start "" %edit% %FILE2% 
)
```

The problem is in "%DIFF%==%NODIFF%: the two vars are always different, even when they should be the same (I've tried with or without "" for the set and the If comparison). To see this, I've tried to echo both var. Here's what I get:

```bash
echo %DIFF%
FC : aucune différence trouvée
echo %NODIFF% 
FC : aucune diff├®rence trouv├®e
```

seems that the encoding is not the same. Most answer I've found for it was to use some chcp (with different values). If I understand it well, it's supposed to change the encoding so that accented characters "works". So i've tried to add

```bash
chcp 65001>nul
```

to my code, but then I got this result:

```bash
echo %DIFF%
FC[?]: aucune diff[?]rence trouv[?]e
echo %NODIFF%
FC : aucune différence trouvée
```

So now the second string is ok, but the first one no more. I've tried others numbers instead of 65001, but they would just make both strings wrong (and not in the same way).

ofc I can also do something like this:

```bash
chcp 850
echo %DIFF%
FC : aucune différence trouvée
chcp 65001
echo %NODIFF%
FC : aucune différence trouvée
```

But then in the IF statement, I can't have change the chcp while doing the comparison.

Have someone an idea on how to make it works?

PS: i'm using cmd and NOT POWERSHELL on windows10 64bits with MINGW.

Comment: seems that file1 and file2 have different encoding. so files will never be the same.

Comment: No, FC gives back "no difference found", so the files ARE the same. 
The problem is that what FC return (i.e. "aucune différence trouvée"), which I store in `%DIFF%`, is not in the same encoding that the variable `%NODIFF%` I set. And thought both variables `%DIFF%` and `%NODIFF%` are never the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wanted to do what you intended, then just narrow your result to verifying just the known standard characters:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Set "FILE1=file1path"
Set "FILE2=file2path"
Set "edit=editorpath"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In (
    '""%__APPDIR__%fc.exe" /A /C /N "%FILE1%" "%FILE2%""') Do Set "DIFF=%%G"
If /I Not "%DIFF%"=="%DIFF: aucune diff=%" (Echo no difference found) Else (
    Start "" "%edit%" "%FILE1%"
    Start "" "%edit%" "%FILE2%")
Exit /B
```

Essentially you're case insensitively comparing two strings, the second with the substring  `aucune diff` removed. If they're not the same, then the substring was part of the string. *Please note that as English versions would use `FC: no differences encountered`, your current idea is still language/locale dependent.*

---

However, in my opinion, there's no need for a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) or to jump through hoops with language/locale dependent strings. You can simply use the returned exit code, *(ErrorLevel)*:

> `2` Could not open at least one of the files.
> `1` Differences found.
> `0` No differences encountered.
> `-1` Invalid syntax used.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Set "FILE1=fileone.cmd"
Set "FILE2=filetwo.cmd"
Set "FILE3=filethree.cmd"
"%__AppDir__%fc.exe" /A /C /N "%FILE1%" "%FILE2%" >NUL 2>&1
If %ERRORLEVEL% Equ 2 (Echo Could not open at least one of the files.
) Else If %ERRORLEVEL% Equ 1 (Start "" "%edit%" "%FILE1%"
    Start "" "%edit%" "%FILE2%") Else If %ERRORLEVEL% Equ 0 (
    Echo No differences encountered.) Else Echo Invalid syntax used.
Pause
GoTo :EOF
```

Although for your purposes, you could simply use `&&` and `||` to conditionally determine if the previous command was successful or not:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Set "FILE1=file1path"
Set "FILE2=file2path"
Set "edit=editorpath"
%__APPDIR__%fc.exe /A /C /N "%FILE1%" "%FILE2%" >NUL 2>&1 && (
    Echo no difference found) || (Start "" "%edit%" "%FILE1%"
    Start "" "%edit%" "%FILE2%")
Exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! At first I just wanted to get the result of FC as a binary but I didn't knew there was ErrorLevel for that! I'll certainly use it :) the first one is still interesting, I totally forgot that we could compare this way -_-